# How to draw or render two objects/textures on same layer libgdx(android)

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a game where I want to show two objects in **same layer** but what is happening right now that the one which I'm writing first in render method is being shown **behind**  the other objects.The object which I have drawn at the last in render method appears **above** all while rendering on screen.Please provide some code or suggestion to keep objects in same layer.For example :

```
       batch.draw(object1,object1.x,object2.y);
       batch.draw(object2,object2.x,object2.y);
```

As of now object 2 is being drawn above object.I want them in same layer. Object1 and Object2 are textures.[image]

As you can see in above image,white eggs falling are appearing behind the man catching those eggs

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "same layer"?  Can you show an image of what you are seeing and of what you would like to see?

Comment: By Same Layer I mean two images at same level not one above or behind another  on screen .Thanks for taking interest

Comment: @P.T. : have a look at the image

Comment: You have to sort the `Texture`s before drawing. I can't think about any other solution...

Comment: @Springrbua : Thanks for rplying but i dont want one above or beneath other sort of thing.

Comment: What else do you want? If 2 `Texture`s overlap, one has to be behind the other :P

Comment: But I dont want thing like that . Is it possible to avoid that ??

Comment: Here is what I think you are trying to accomplish: Eggs will be drawn in front of the man, but behind the basket and hand ?

Comment: Then you need to split your "man on skate" to 2 textures. One containing the body and another containing the basket and arm. Then render following textures (body, all eggs, arm with a basket) in that order.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to render one image above another one. As you already found out, the ones that come first in your render-loop will be drawn behind the ones that come later.

If you would like to stick with rendering Textures directly, you will have to sort the drawing order somehow.

One other way is to use scene2D... Scene2D offers the `Stage` class, which lets you add your images to it. The same way here, the items added first will be drawn first and the others will be drawn above.

Luckily, you can change the order within scene2d quickly by changing the z-value of each item. Items with higher z-value will be drawn in front of others. This way it's way easier to reorder how you draw stuff.

As it seems in your picture, you are trying to collect eggs within the basket, so you will have to split your chicken and basket into two different images. The chicken will be drawn first (after the background of course) and then the eggs. Coming last in the draw order you need to render your basket. This way the eggs will be falling down in front of the chicken, but will be rendered behind hte basket, so it looks like they are landing into it.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Watch out for zIndex in scene2d, it is per group. You can never make actors in a one group appear below AND above those in another group.

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot to mention that... :)